# Unexpectful output format of str() function

Tags: r, csv

I`m running such a sequence of commands:

```
read_csv = read.csv('D:/winequality-white.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(read_csv)
```

In the result I get:

```
'data.frame':   4898 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ fixed.acidity.volatile.acidity.citric.acid.residual.sugar.chlorides.free.sulfur.dioxide.total.sulfur.dioxide.density.pH.sulphates.alcohol.quality: chr  "7;0.27;0.36;20.7;0.045;45;170;1.001;3;0.45;8.8;6" "6.3;0.3;0.34;1.6;0.049;14;132;0.994;3.3;0.49;9.5;6" "8.1;0.28;0.4;6.9;0.05;30;97;0.9951;3.26;0.44;10.1;6" "7.2;0.23;0.32;8.5;0.058;47;186;0.9956;3.19;0.4;9.9;6" ...
```

But I expected an output`s format like this one:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id    : int  10 11 12 13
 $ name  : chr  "sai" "ram" NA "sahithi"
 $ dob   : chr  "1990-10-02" "1981-03-24" "1987-06-14" "1985-08-16"
 $ gender: chr  "M" "" "F" "F"
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

The link on the dataset: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv

Comment: `read.csv` uses commas as separators, your data set has semi-colons. Try `read.table(<filename>, header = TRUE, sep = ";")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `read.csv` uses commas as separators.

Your data set has semi-colons. Try `read.table(<filename>, header = TRUE, sep = ";")`.

Comment: This is [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73966171/unexpectful-output-format-of-str-function?noredirect=1#comment130600541_73966171) word by word without a reference to the original. Care to explain?